# getting Error: EPERM: operation not permitted error while using react native and android emulator with vscode

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, mobile-development

```
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'D:\coding\reactNative\EcommerceApp\.git\fsmonitor--daemon\cookies\53648-318'
Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
    at D:\coding\reactNative\EcommerceApp\node_modules\metro-file-map\src\watchers\NodeWatcher.js:231:14 {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'lstat',
  path: 'D:\\coding\\reactNative\\EcommerceApp\\.git\\fsmonitor--daemon\\cookies\\53648-318'
}
```

I'm using Node.js v18.18.2

I am getting this error again and again.
I have seen multiple solutions like `npx react-native start --reset-cache` and `npm run android` or
`cd android ./gradlew clean cd .. npx react-native run-android`
But my project doesn't have an Android folder as I used `npx create-expo-app` expo command for project creation.

How do we fix this error?